# issue when using bridge connection

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware, virtualization, vmware-workstation

I have a windows 10 host machine connected to internet through wifi. . I have installed vmware workstation in it.

I have created a linux virt machine and set a static ip address and used a bridged connection.

Each time I start the vmware machine intenet connection on all pc of the office is dropped. It is not an ip confict problem because other pc get range of ip from 192.168.1.100 to 200. The host and vmware machine have 192.168.1.12 and 192.168.1.23.
Everything is ok when I use NAT.

May sb help me please? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want a static ip you need to set it on the machine (here a VM) and the router/dhcp server so that it knows this machine doesn't need an ip and which ip it has...